# Basic question on ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, functions, derivatives

I may be asking something very basic, but consider the two ODEs
$$
\begin{align}
1.\,\,f'(x)&=af(x)\\
2.\,\,f'(x)&=af(x)+b(f(x))^2
\end{align}
$$
Naturally, if $b=0$, the two ODEs are identical. However, that does not happen with the solution of each. For the first one, we have (computed in *Mathematica 13*)
$$
f_1(x)=C_1e^{ax}
$$
and for the second
$$
f_2(x)=\frac{ae^{a(x+C_2)}}{1-be^{a(x+C_2)}}
$$
However, when $b=0$,
$$
f_2(x)=ae^{a(x+C_2)}
$$
which does not equal $f_1(x)$. Why is that? Since these work for any constants $C_1,C_2$, do I need to rewrite the solution by solving
$$
f_1(x)=f_2(x)\Leftrightarrow C_1=ae^{aC_2}
$$
What am I missing?

Comment: You kinda answered your own question there. $C_1$ is as constant and so is $ae^{aC_2}$. They might as well equal each other for the same initial conditions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no contradiction. When in ODE's we use constants these can be arbitrary constants and so we get a family of curves for all values of the constant. If you set
$C=ae^{c_{1}}$ then you again obtain the same family of curves. Constants are NOT fixed. They can take any value in $\mathbb{R}$.